# I spend too much time in finding a function which looks very simple

Tags: calculus, power-series

I know maybe my questions is ridiculous because of my weak knowledge of mathematics, but I really spend a lot of time in this and I even can’t find a possible answer.
Here is the statement of questions:

Find a function $ S ( x ) $ satisfies:
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^2}$$

Comment: Hint, try differentiating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of the special function $Li_2(x)$. It can't be written in terms of standard functions.

Comment: Alright, I waste time successfully once again

Comment: @Chisato2233 if you type the sum into WolframAlpha, it will tell you that that is the definition of $Li_2$. WolframAlpha knows lots of special functions, so can be very helpful for determining which formulae can actually be written in terms of standard functions, to avoid wasting time in the future.